# PHP/HTML Export table as pdf?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, printing

I have a HTML table that displays data from a db using PHP, I'd like to give an option to print the table out (as a button). I thought that exporting as a pdf would be the simplest option to do this. This is how I have the table laid out.

```html
<table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">

  <tr><th>Refund ID</th><th>Customer ID</th><th>Manager ID</th><th>Customer Name</th><th>Amount Refunded</th><th>Refund Date/Time</th><th>Details</th></tr>

  <?php 
     //some php code...

     echo '<tr>'; 
     echo '<td>'. $idRefund[$i] .'</td>'; 
     echo '<td>'. $idCustomer[$i] .'</td>'; 
     echo '<td>'. $idManager[$i] .'</td>'; 
     echo '<td>'. $customerName[$i] .'</td>'; 
     echo '<td>'. $amount[$i] .'</td>'; 
     echo '<td>'. $dateTime[$i] .'</td>'; 
     echo '<td>'. $details[$i] .'</td>'; 
     echo '</tr>';
     $i++; 
 ?>

</table>
```

How would I go about printing this table using php or javascript or even exporting as a pdf if thats more simplistic.

edit: I ended up using mPDF which is very similar to FPDF in terms of the methods available to use. The help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can use tcpdf to create pdf in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The PDF Generator**

```
    $pdf=new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
    $pdf->Output();
?
```

To generate a pdf file, first we need to include library file `fpdf.php`. Then we need to create an FPDF object using the default constructor `FPDF()`. This constructor can be passed three values namely page orientation (portrait or landscape), measure unit, and page size (A4, A5, etc.,). By default pages are in A4 portrait and the measure unit is millimeter. It could have been specified explicitly with:

```
$pdf=new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
```

It is possible to use landscape (L), other page formats (such as Letter and Legal) and measure units (pt, cm, in).

Then we have added a page to our pdf document with `AddPage()`. The origin is at the upper-left corner and the current position is by default placed at 1 cm from the borders; the margins can be changed with the function `SetMargins()`.

To print a text, we need to first select a font with `SetFont()`. Let us select Arial bold 16

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
```

We use `Cell()` function to output a text. A cell is a rectangular area, possibly framed, which contains some text. It is output at the current position. We specify its dimensions, its text (centered or aligned), if borders should be drawn, and where the current position moves after it (to the right, below or to the beginning of the next line). To add a frame, we would do this:

```
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World !',1);
```

Finally, the document is closed and sent to the browser with `Output()`. We could have saved it in a file by passing the desired file name.

> To learn Fpdf:  [Click Here](http://www.fpdf.org.)
>   To refer about this code : [Click Here](http://www.macronimous.com/resources/Converting_HTML2PDF_using_PHP.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [KnpLabs/snappy](https://github.com/), it generates PDF from a url or a html page.